# Calculating age base on Months to birthday javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm calculating a user's age based on his date of birth. It works alright. But I want that when it is **6 months to his/her birthday**, the age should be rounded up.

I use [jquery input mask plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/), to provide mask date.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
      <header>
        <h3>Calculate Age from Date of Birth</h3>
      </header>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control mask-date" id="dob" placeholder="Date of Birth">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="age" placeholder="Age">
      </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.mask-date').mask("99/99/9999",{placeholder:"mm/dd/yyyy"});

    $('#dob').blur(function(event) {
       var dob = $('#dob').val();
       dob = new Date(dob);
       var today = new Date();

       var age = Math.floor((today-dob)/ (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
       console.log(age); 
    });
```

Comment: Does Math.round() not work?

Comment: @JamesT, The problem is not in calculating the age, but to round it off, if it is 6 months to the person's birthday.

Comment: Yes, use Math.round to round it off instead of Math.floor.. see GOTO 0's answer

Comment: Math.round() still produce the same results!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your JavaScript blur handler, replace `Math.floor` with [`Math.round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round):

```
var age = Math.round((today-dob)/ (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
```

Comment: The age calculations works for me, but I want to round the age up, if it is 6 months to the person's birthday.

Comment: As it stands, now, when I use Math.round() it produces the same results.

Comment: Math.round will round .5 or higher up instead of down. If you're not getting the correct result, you're not calculating the 6 month boundary correctly. 8y 6m should equal 8.5 => 9.

Comment: @ultrasamad `Math.round` should work for your purpose. If it doesn't do what you want, consider adding some examples of birth dates and the ages you expect to your question.

Comment: @GOTO0, thanks I think the problem was with the age I input. Thanks for pointing out that, and still maintaining your stand that Math.round() should work if I give the correct data.

Comment: @ultrasamad No problem, happy I could help.

Comment: @GOTO0, Lol, :-D  I think my brain was hot a bit, so I couldn't figure things out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should strongly consider using the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library. It is a very powerful date/time manipulation library for JavaScript and used extensively in the industry. The documentation is comprehensive and I'm sure you'll find many of the other date functions useful.

Download it and add the script source before your JavaScript.

**New Javascript**

```
$('#dob').blur(function(event) {
   // convert date into moment date object (specifying the format)
   var dob = moment($('#dob').val(), 'MM/DD/YYYY');

   // you can format the date easily
   console.log(dob.format('DD/MMM/YYYY');   // 01/Jan/2001

   // you can output the date from now which rounds the year as you want
   console.log(dob.fromNow());
});
```

**Outputs**

Date today: 25th Jan 2017 (01/25/2017)

```
dob = '10/01/2017' // in 8 months
dob = '01/20/2016' // a year ago
dob = '08/20/2015' // a year ago
dob = '07/20/2015' // 2 years ago (rounding by 6 months as you expect)
```

Answer (score 1):

using moment its easy

```
let years = moment().diff(birthdate, 'years');
let months = moment().diff(birthdate, 'months');
let days = moment().diff(birthdate, 'days');
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

No every year has same count of days. So it is easier to make substract between years and do correction based on month and day

```
var d1 = new Date(); // current day
var d2 = new Date(1999, 5, 16); // born day

var age = d1.getFullYear() - d2.getFullYear();
if (d1.getMonth()<d2.getMonth() || d1.getMonth() == d2.getMonth() && d1.getDay() < d2.getDay())
{
 age = age - 1;
}

// here is actual age in "age"
```